# How to center perfect masonry? (isotope)

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

Using isotope with the [extension of perfectMasonry by zonear](https://github.com/zonear/isotope-perfectmasonry)

So far it looks like it is working well, all I am wondering is if anyone knows how to center the container. Tried with css with no luck. Original isotope [has centered masonry](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/custom-layout-modes/centered-masonry.html)

Anyone?
Thanks

**>> UPDATE <<**

new isotope (v2) is out and it does the "perfect masonry" bit  with a [layoutmode called packery](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/packery.html). Also the new isotope version [does center masonry/isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html#isfitwidth). But I don't actually use `fitWidth` as I simply use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and isotope applied on top to get centered masonry at layout start (not centering once filtered tho, for that use `fitWidth`)

Comment: Second link is broken.

Comment: @Mizipzor thanks, updated. D. Desandro at Metafizzy moved the v1 location.

Comment: For isotope v2 users, the [docs state](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html#fitwidth) that _fitWidth_ is only compatible with fixed-size columns, not with percentage positioning - which makes sense: if you have tiles that are 25% of the container width, then change the container size, the tiles inside it resize as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice to hear that you found the extension. :) Currently the only way to get it centered is to have a specific width on the container. Of course, if you want your design to be responsive (why wouldn't you) this, as a pure CSS solution, is not viable.

For responsive layouts you need to do it "by hand" - Bind a resize trigger to the window and on every resize, calculate how wide the container would need to be (knowing your tile widths). I will bake this capability into the extension at some point when I get the time. Hope this helps. :)

---

Edit: The perfectMasonry now supports centering the layout by pure CSS, as it now gets width specified. So, simple margin auto for the container CSS should do the trick. Like so.

```
#container {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! How about having an horizontal layout? In the code you specify the height, thought I could set a container height and have the layout horizontal, but it isn't working (Or i haven't managed to)

Comment: Oh, you mean that it would scroll sideways?

Comment: yep.. generally your extension is perfect in terms of perfect masonry. But what if I wanted to center the layout?Or what If I wanted an horizontal layout (yes that it'd scrolld sideways) with a container fixed height? 

David has them both:

Centered: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/centered-masonry.html

Horizontal: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/layout-modes.html#masonryhorizontal

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't support those at the moment. :/ It didn't even occur to me that someone would like to set it horizontally. :P

Comment: to be honest I was just playing around. Actually what I wanted to do was to have the container fluid or at least be able to center the layout without the need of using a fixed width :)

Comment: or peraphs having % width/height boxes? :P

Comment: I added the ability to have the layout centered. Check out the edits in the original answer. :)

Comment: Just to let you know - PerfectMasonry now has both, horizontal and fluid layouts :)

Comment: Wen i try your example.html on the desktop and I resize the browser to a mobile view 320pxw, I get one box bigger than the browser and a hor scrollbar. I thought liquid would adjust to the browser size and be good for mobiles too then

Comment: Hi, this works perfectly as I am using it. But I am on the fluid layout and the items do not resize to 1005 when on mobile view. how can I reset them to 1005 width when on mobile? e.g. <767